# Is it possible to use SteelSeries keyboards with MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

Is it possible to use SteelSeries keyboards with MacBook Pro?

I'm thinking about SteelSeries Apex line.

Answer (score 3):

I have a macbook pro and a SteelSeries m500. It works great. All you have to do is go into System Preferences -> Keyboards and remap the command, control, alt... keys to what you want. Super easy. I also use Better Touch Tool to remap the function keys at the top to what I want: https://folivora.ai/